# Addings Rows in Element In Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm trying to display rows using the Element IO in VueJs. My problem is why is my code not outputting and how can i add some rows and remove some rows? Is there something wrong with my code? I've attached a v-for but it seems it can't work. I'm sorry i'm new to element-ui. Please see my code below.Thank you.

```
<template>
    <div>

        <el-form>
            <el-table v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>

                    <el-table-column
                            sortable="true"
                            label="Item">
              <template>
                 <el-input v-model="item.item_id"></el-input>
              </template>
                    </el-table-column>

                    <el-table-column
                            sortable="true"
                            label="Quantity">
                            <template>
                 <el-input v-model="item.quantity"></el-input>
              </template>
                    </el-table-column>

                    <el-table-column
                            sortable="true"
                            label="Unit">
                            <template>
                 <el-input v-model="item.quantity"></el-input>
              </template>
                    </el-table-column>

                    <el-table-column
                            sortable="true"
                            label="Unit Price">
                            <template>
                 <el-input v-model="item.unit_price"></el-input>
              </template>
                    </el-table-column>

                    <el-table-column
                            fixed="right"
                            property="action"
                            label="Action">
                            <template>
                                    <el-button type="danger" size="small">Remove</el-button>
                            </template>
                    </el-table-column>

            </el-table>
            <br>
            <el-form-item style="float:right;">
                <el-button type="submit" @click.prevent="createNewPurchaseOrder">Create</el-button>
                <el-button>Cancel</el-button>
            </el-form-item>
        </el-form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          item_id: '1',
          quantity: '8',
          unit_id: 'Gram',
          unit_price: '100'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createNewPurchaseOrder () {
      console.log(this.$data)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate your self. el-table component from Element-Ui is taking a array as data props to work. See [Table Props for el-table component in ElementUI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-attributes)

This should works :

```
<el-table :data="items">
  ...
</el-table>
```

Each `el-table-column` must be a key of your item in your item list by adding `prop='myKey'` to each `el-table-column`

For exemple if I got a array of items like this :

```
[{
  id : 12,
  firstname : "John",
  lastname : "Doe"
}]
```

I will have a table like this

```
<el-table :data="items">
  <el-table-column prop="id" label="ID">...</el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="firstname" label="Firstname">...</el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="lastname " label="Lastname">...</el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

When you will remove or add an item to your array, the :data props of the `el-table` will be reactive to changes.

Answer (score 0):

Take more look [at element table documentation](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table)

You have to pass a `data` property to `el-table` and a `prop` property to `el-table-column`

```
<template>
<div>

    <el-form>
        <el-table :data="items" :key='index'>

          [...]
        </el-table>
        <br>
        <el-form-item style="float:right;">
            <el-button type="submit" @click.prevent="createNewPurchaseOrder">Create</el-button>
            <el-button>Cancel</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
</div>
```